# Display of error messages not happening from HTML to php

Tags: php, html, xampp

Am using php and HTML to perform validations to a form. My HTML code looks like this:

```
<head>
   <style>
      .error {color: #FF0000;}
   </style>
</head>
<body style="background-color:#F2F2F2">
   <form name="htmlform" method="post" action="test1.php" >
      <table width="550px" table align="center" frame="box" height="80%" style="margin-    top:25px;margin-bottom:25px; background-color:#ffffff;border-radius:5px;">
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th colspan="2">
               <h3  align="center">Write to Us</h3>
               <hr>
            </th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td valign="top">
               <label for="name">Name </label>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
               <input  type="text" name="name" maxlength="50" size="30">
               <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td valign="top">
               <label for="email">Email Address </label>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
               <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">
               <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td valign="top">
               <label for="telephone">Telephone Number</label>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
               <input  type="text" name="telephone1" maxlength="30" size="30">
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td valign="top">
               <label for="message">Message </label>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
               <textarea  name="message1" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea>
               <span class="error">* <?php echo $messageErr;?></span>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">
               <input type="submit" value="Submit" >
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </form>
</body>
```

and my PHP code looks like this:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
 if (empty($_POST["name"]))
 {$nameErr = "Name is required";}
 else
 {$name = test_input($_POST["name"]);}

 if (empty($_POST["email"]))
 {$emailErr = "Email is required";}
 else
 {$email = test_input($_POST["email"]);}

 if (empty($_POST["telephone1"]))
 {$telephone1 = "";}
 else
 {$telephone1 = test_input($_POST["telephone1"]);}

 if (empty($_POST["message1"]))
 {$messageErr = "Message is required";}
 else
 {$message1 = test_input($_POST["message1"]);}
}

function test_input($data)
{
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
}

echo "<h2>Your Input:</h2>";
echo $name;
echo "<br>";
echo $email;
echo "<br>";
echo $telephone1;
echo "<br>";
echo $message1;
?>
```

when am trying to display those error messages when name, email, message fields are empty it is just going to test1.php page and displaying blank data though the fields are empty in registration form. Am using XAMP server to execute my files.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are both the code in same php? i.e. test1.php?

Comment: try to use your php code on same file above html code and leave form action blank

Comment: php is in different file and html in another file. If i have to use php in same file of html how to use

Comment: If the filename is html, rename it to php, then paste the code on top of the page. thats it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code..its working.But make sure you have 2 pages with extension .php

add below code in your php file.

```
 <?php
 if (empty($_POST["name"]))
 {$nameErr = "Name is required";}
 else
 {$name =test_input($_POST["name"]);}

 if (empty($_POST["email"]))
 {$emailErr = "Email is required";}
 else
 {$email = test_input($_POST["email"]);}

 if (empty($_POST["telephone1"]))
 {$telephone1 = "";}
 else
 {$telephone1 =test_input($_POST["telephone1"]);}

 if (empty($_POST["message1"]))
 {$messageErr = "Message is required";}
 else
 {$message1 = test_input($_POST["message1"]);}

function test_input($data)
{
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
}
if(isset($name) && isset($email) && isset($message1))
{
echo "<h2>Your Input:</h2>";
echo $name;
echo "<br>";
echo $email;
echo "<br>";
echo $telephone1;
echo "<br>";
echo $message1;
}

$from = $email;
$to = 'YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS';
$subject = 'Call Back Enquiry';
$fullname=$name;
$mobile=$telephone1;
$emailid=$email;
$message=$message1;
$body="Full Name:".$fullname."\n\n"."Mobile:".$mobile."\n\n"."Email:".$emailid."\n\n"."Message:".$message1;

$headers = array(
    'From' => $from,
    'To' => $to,
    'Subject' => $subject
);

$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array(
        'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'port' => '465',
        'auth' => true,
        'username' => 'YOUR MAIL ID',
        'password' => 'YOUR PASSWORD'
    ));

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
    echo('<p>' . $mail->getMessage() . '</p>');
} else {
   // echo('<p>Message successfully sent!</p>');
}
?>
```

and in your another php file which consits html code,write below code in it.

```
<?php include('test.php')?>
<head>
   <style>
      .error {color: #FF0000;}
   </style>
</head>
<body style="background-color:#F2F2F2">
   <form name="htmlform" method="post">
      <table width="550px" table align="center" frame="box" height="80%" style="margin-    top:25px;margin-bottom:25px; background-color:#ffffff;border-radius:5px;">
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th colspan="2">
               <h3  align="center">Write to Us</h3>
               <hr>
            </th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td valign="top">
               <label for="name">Name </label>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
               <input  type="text" name="name" maxlength="50" size="30" value="<?php if(isset($name)){echo $name;}?>">
               <span class="error">* <?php if(isset($nameErr)){echo $nameErr;}?></span>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td valign="top">
               <label for="email">Email Address </label>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
               <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30" value="<?php if(isset($email)){echo $email;}?>">
               <span class="error">* <?php if(isset($emailErr)){echo $emailErr;}?></span>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td valign="top">
               <label for="telephone">Telephone Number</label>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
               <input  type="text" name="telephone1" maxlength="30" size="30" value="<?php if(isset($telephone1)){echo $telephone1;}?>">
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td valign="top">
               <label for="message">Message </label>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
               <textarea  name="message1" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6"><?php if(isset($message1)){echo $message1;}?></textarea>
               <span class="error">* <?php if(isset($messageErr)){echo $messageErr;}?></span>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">
               <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" name="submit" >
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </form>
</body>
```

Comment: its working fine King but i want that PHP to be in another file and would like to perform validation and after that it should be send as a mail to that receipient

Comment: hi,any body please help me if i have to call PHP file to html file separately because while executing in word press it is not identifying php code which is given

Comment: @Pallavipradeep i have edited my code,please check it and tell me is it according to your requirement or not ?

Comment: hi King thanks for solution. But here Registration.php which you have given can i make it as html and call that php file.

Comment: i tried saving to Registration.html instead Registration.php then inside text boxes it shown all the php code which you wrote like this "<?php if(isset($name)){echo $name;}?>" and when click on submit it is not performing any action. If i make Registration.php and execute it works very beautiful as expected. I require this html  page which calls php code and send a mail after validations are true.

Comment: Your code was helpfulto me. But with same code i should send a mail to  fixed mail id giving all details of which user has entered in registration form.

Comment: King, am getting this error "Warning: Illegal string offset 'headers' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Registration\test_form.php on line 36" i have kept your code at when the condition is true and kept all your mailing statments....

Comment: just comment that 2 lines starts with $message['headers'] and also remove $message['headers'] from the mail function and then try and tell me what happens ?

Comment: i have commented that two lines which has $message['headers'] and removed as you said still am not getting any mail to the specified mail address

Comment: yes local host of xamp server and i have set smtp=stmtp.gmail.com in php.ini config file

Comment: ok..then it will not work,mail function works on live server.wait i give you another code which might work in localhost

Comment: i have edited my code..try that and change the email id and password where instruction is given like "YOUR MAIL ID","YOUR PASSWORD"

Comment: it is giving error at this point "$smtp = Mail::factory(" as Fatal error: Class 'Mail' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\Registration\test_form.php on line 46

Comment: first of all you have to install php in your platform then and then it will support, or using my previous code,i mean use mail function instead of smtp,and check on live server.

Comment: Hi King, Thanks for your support. when i tested that piece of code in Live server it is working fine.

Comment: its my pleasure...i hope my answer helps you

Comment: @Pallavipradeep if it works then accept my answer for the appreciation.

Answer (score 1):

Change form tag to post to the same page, by setting action to ""

```
<form name="htmlform" method="post" action="" >
```

This will make your form post to the same page. Put all the php code on top of your current page which has the html. By doing so, all your php variables will be available in the html.

Comment: With your help am able to stay in the same page. But i have to perform validations for the input fields i have entered or not entered. so how to do it.

Comment: validations are working fine when i changed my file name extension from html to php. But it clears previous data and displays empty in those fields with error message